# Font "Avenir" not found by fontspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec

I'm compiling my document using Xelatex and Lualatex and have set the main font to "Avenir".

`\setmainfont{Avenir}`

But, I keep getting the error,

`! Package fontspec Error: The font "Avenir" cannot be found.`

I'm running,

```tex
TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX)
kpathsea version 6.3.3
```

I know that I can load the font by downloading the font and giving the filename path, but why does `\setmainfont{Avenir}` not work?

Comment: I get that error too, do you have that font?

Comment: If you have the font, use `otfinfo` with the `-a` option to get the name of the version you have.

Comment: Doesn't fontspec come with the Avenir font?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `fontspec` doesn’t come with *any* fonts. Moreover, as Avenir is a proprietary font (which doesn’t allow redistribution), it wouldn’t be included in any case in free LaTeX distributions.